# Generics and parameterized types in Java

Tags: java

The below code causes a compile time error :

> The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Object) in the type
>   List is not   applicable for the
>   arguments (String)

code :

```
List<? extends Object> a1 = new ArrayList();
a1.add("string");
```

Error is at line :

```
a1.add("string");
```

Since class String extends from Object why ref a1 not accept a String type ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend reading this article, http://java.dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance. (Italic additions are mine)

> In summary, we use covariance *`<? extends Object>`* when we only intend to take generic
>   values out of a structure. We use contravariance *`<? super Object>`* when we only intend
>   to put generic values into a structure and we use an invariant *`<Object>`* when we
>   intend to do both.

You defined your list as holding a covariant Object type, which means you can write `Object o = a1.get(1)` but you can't write `a1.add("foo")`. If you want to be able to add Objects but not get them back, then you would need to define your list like this:

```
List<? super Object> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

It's a bit unfortunate, in my opinion, language authors used the terms `extend` and `super` to indicate covariance and contravariance, especially in the above example since there is no super type of `Object`.

Answer (score 4):

`? extends Object` means "some unknown type `X` that extends `Object`". By trying to add a `String` to the collection, you're essentially claiming `X = String`, which the compiler cannot verify. As far as the compiler knows, `X` could just as well be `Integer` or something completely different.

In other words `List<? extends Object>` does NOT mean "anything that extends `Object` goes". A simple `List<Object>` means that.

Answer (score 1):

`List<? extends Object>` can be used with every type of lists.

How do you think, would it be safe to let it add any objects if for example

```
List<? extends Object> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
a1.add("string");
```

Only safe value to add would be `null` since it doesn't belong to any specific type.

To get rid of this problem you can use for example `List<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>()` or `List a1 = new ArrayList()`